# sqlalchemy + pandas parameterized query string execution error

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

host = "xxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com"
user = "user1"
pwd = "xxx"
database = "db1"


engine = create_engine("mysql+pymysql://{}:{}@{}/{}".format(user,pwd,host,database), echo=True)


query1 = """
         select * 
         from tbl1 
         where dt <= :cutoff_dt
         """


params={
        "cutoff_dt": "2023-9-30"
       }

# Begin transaction and create session
with engine.begin() as conn:
    try:
        # Execute your query
        df1 = pd.read_sql(
                  query1, 
                  conn, 
                  params=params
                 )

    except Exception as e:
        # Handle any errors
        print(f"Error occurred: {e}")
        conn.rollback()  # Rollback transaction if error occurs

    finally:
        # Close connection and rollback if not explicit (safer)
        conn.close()  # Explicitly close the connection even if no error
```

Error:

[parameters: {'cutoff_dt': '2023-9-30'}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/f405)
2024-02-13 11:14:16,745 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine ROLLBACK

Comment: Looks like an error in your SQL, maybe wrong table name or input type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the parameter placeholder (`:cutoff`). It is being passed as-is to `pymysql`, which doesn't recognise it as a placeholder and so doesn't replace it with the parameter value.

You can either:

- use pymysql's formatting:

  ```py
  query1 = """SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE dt <= %(cutoff)s"""
  ```
- wrap the query with sqlalchemy.text so that `:cutoff` is handled correctly

  ```py
  query1 = sqlalchemy.text("""SELECT * FROM tbl1 WHERE dt <= :cutoff""")
  ```